# Print first letter of each word in a line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have searched through other posts and have not found an answer that fits my needs. I have a file that is space delimited. I would like to print the first letter of each word in the given line. For example:

```
cat test.txt
This is a test sentence.
```

Using either sed, awk, or a combination, I would like the output to be "Tiats". Any advice on pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: In Haskell: `main = putStr =<< (unlines . map (map head . words) . lines <$> getContents)`

Comment: Remind me to never try to learn Haskell. I though _Perl_ was bad :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, it only looks bad because I wrote it to fit on one line. I would never write it like that for real.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility:

```
pax> echo 'This is a test sentence.
  This is another.' | sed -e 's/$/ /' -e 's/\([^ ]\)[^ ]* /\1/g' -e 's/^ *//'
Tiats
Tia
```

The first `sed` command simply ensures there's a space at the end of each line to simplify the second command.

The second command will strip all subsequent letters and the trailing spaces from each word. A word in this sense is defined as any group of non-space characters.

The third is something added to ensure leading spaces on each line are removed.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution with **sed**:

```
sed 's/\(.\)[^ ]* */\1/g' File
```

Here, we look for `any character`(`.`) followed by a `sequence of non-space characters`(`[^ ]*`) followed by `optional space`( `*`). Replace this pattern with the `first` character(character matched by `.`).

**Sample:**

```
$ cat File
This is a test sentence.
Ahggsh Mathsh Dansdjksj
$ sed 's/\(.\)[^ ]* */\1/g' File
Tiats
AMD
```

Comment: Easiest solution and adjustable. I needed to parse a single word filled with '-', so I used `sed -e 's/\(.\)[^-]*-*/\1/g'`.
`echo This-is-my-string | sed -e 's/\(.\)[^-]*-*/\1/g'
Tims`

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
awk '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    printf(substr($i, 1, 1));
  }
  printf("\n");
}' input_file
```

awk automagically sets NF to be the number of fields in the line, loop through each one and use `substr` to get the first letter

Answer (score 2):

A funny pure Bash solution:

```
while read -r line; do
    read -r -d '' -a ary <<< "$line"
    printf '%c' "${ary[@]}" $'\n'
done < text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=substr($i,1,1)}1' OFS= file
```

This loops trough every word and cut off all except first letter.

Eks:

```
cat file
This is a test sentence.
Ahggsh Mathsh Dansdjksj
```

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=substr($i,1,1)}1' OFS= file
Tiats
AMD
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, surprisingly difficult task until I found this thread. ... I wanted to extract the first letter in a string of words.  This worked:

```sh
echo 'Apple banana Carrot fruit-cake (Grapes)' | sed -r 's/.*/\L&/; s/-/ /g; s/[()]//g; s/(.)[^ ]* */\1/g'
abcfcg
```

i.e.

```sh
sed -r 's/.*/\L&/; s/-/ /g; s/[()]//g; s/(.)[^ ]* */\1/g'
```

- `\L&` lowercases the string (to uppercase, use: `\U&`)
- replace `-` with space
- remove parentheses `()`
- last expression per other answers here, notably @arjun-mathew-dan

  - look for any character: `(.)`
  - followed by a sequence of non-space characters: `[^ ]*`
  - followed by optional space:  `*`
  - replace this pattern with the first character [matched by `(.)` ]: `\1`

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```
$ echo This is a test sentence | perl -nE 'print for /^\w|(?<=\W)./g'
Tiats
```

Explanation: Print any non-white-space character, which is beginning of the line, or preceded by a white-space.

Answer (score 0):

Another perl command.

```
$ echo 'This is a test sentence.' | perl -nE 'print for m/(?<!\S)\S/g;print "\n"'
Tiats
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/ *\([^ ]\)[^ ]\{1,\} */\1/g' YourFile
```

Take directly all space length and place. Assuming just that space are the space character and not a tab (but could easily be adapted for)

just for fun

```
sed 's/ *\(\([^ ]\)\)\{1,\} */\2/g' YourFile
```

take the last letter instead of first

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, on one line:

```
main = putStr =<< (unlines . map (map head . words) . lines <$> getContents)
```

Perhaps more readably:

```hs
main = do
  line <- getLine  --Read a single line from stdin
  let allWords = words line --Turn the line into a list of words
  let firsts = map head allWords --Get the first letter of each word
  putStrLn firsts --Print them out
  main --Start over
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B.\|[[:space:][:punct:]]//g' file
```

Delete all characters following the beginning of a word, spaces and punctuation.